# Saving camera images android .... they're roated 90 degrees

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am using commonware's camera sample to try and create an android app that takes a picture.  The preview shows the camera rotated 90 degrees and I've corrected that by applying:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

However, the images are still saved rotated 90 degrees the other way.  How can I adjust this so that when the images are saved, they're saved in the same "aspect" as that of the viewer?

Please advise,
TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517200/photo-rotate-90-degree-while-capture-in-some-phones) , this happens only in some devices and it depends on the manufacturer.

I managed to workaround this issue by detecting the orientation angle of the device and apply the rotation accordingly, like this:

```
            ExifInterface exitInterface = new ExifInterface(imagePath);

            int orientation = exitInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            int degree = 0;

            switch (orientation){
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;
            }
```

Then I rotate my bitmap using a custom method:

```
    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap src, float degree) 
{
        // create new matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // setup rotation degree
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmp;
}
```