# Image rotate 90 degree using camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

Hello I am working on one android app where I need to capture the image using camera `intent` and set the bitmap in the `imageview` but here bitmap is rotated by 90 degree. I have checked many threads of stackoverflow like [Photo rotate 90 degree while capture in some phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517200/photo-rotate-90-degree-while-capture-in-some-phones) but did not work for me.

Here when I am executing this `exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);` then it is returning 0 `ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED` and in my `getImage` function no condition is satisfying.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
capturedPhotoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        capturedPhotoName);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST);
```

onActivityResult

```
Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Bitmap bitmap;
try {
    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,
            selectedImage);
    bitmap = Util.getImage(bitmap, selectedImage.toString());
    mPictureImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("New Issue Activity", e.toString());
}

/**
 * Get the image orientation
 * 
 * @param imagePath
 * @return orietation angle
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static Bitmap getImage(Bitmap bitmap, String path) throws IOException {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
    int orientation = exif
            .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
        m.postRotate(180);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
        return bitmap;
    } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        m.postRotate(90);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
        return bitmap;
    } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        m.postRotate(270);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
        return bitmap;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: What device are you testing on? There is a bug in certain devices and you need to handle that.

Comment: Testing on Sony, I tried to handle that but did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I implemented one photo take activity which you can take the photo and set the orientation of the photo. It is supported by every device I tested including Samsung galaxy series, tablets, sony xperia series, tablets.

You can check out my accepted answer about rotation of images on this topic:

[Camera capture orientation on samsung devices in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203369/camera-capture-orientation-on-samsung-devices-in-android/18203715#18203715)

If you also need to save and use that image that you have rotated, saving and using the photo functions additional to my answer I gave above:

savePhoto function:

```
public void savePhoto(Bitmap bmp) {

        imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                cc.getDirectoryName());
        imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date.toString() + ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            scanPhoto(imageFileName.toString());
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

scanPhoto function:

```
public void scanPhoto(final String imageFileName) {
        geniusPath = imageFileName;
        msConn = new MediaScannerConnection(MyClass.this,
                new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        msConn.scanFile(imageFileName, null);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        msConn.disconnect();

                    }
                });
        msConn.connect();
    }
```

SavePhotoTask class:

```
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "photo.jpg");
            if (photo.exists()) {
                photo.delete();
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
                fos.write(jpeg[0]);
                fos.close();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            }
            return (null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this bug seems to prop in Samsung devices, the OP is finding it difficult to do on a Sony device.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:-

```
                    Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
                    imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.toString());  
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);  
                    Bitmap bitmap = Utility.getOrientationFromExif(new Utility().compressImage1(imageFile.toString(),((Activity)context)),orientation);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 50 , bos);
```

**Utility.java**

```
public class Utility
{

    public Bitmap compressImage1(String imageUri, Activity act)
    {
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri, act);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not
        // loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        // Bitmap bmp = decodeBitmap(Uri.parse(imageUri), 612, 816, act);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of
        // the original image
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 612, 816);

        // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low
        // on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

            // load the bitmap from its path
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        return bmp;
    }           


    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }



    public static Bitmap getOrientationFromExif(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation)
    {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        int newWidth = 612;
        int newHeight = 816;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
//              matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
//              matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
//              matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
//              matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try
        {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: On this `exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);` then it is returning 0 ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED and in your code there is no such case of ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED

Answer (score -1):

This function worked for me, try your luck.

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bmp, String imageUrl) {
    if (bmp != null) {
        ExifInterface ei;
        int orientation = 0;
        try {
            ei = new ExifInterface(imageUrl);
            orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        // etc.
        }

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmpWidth,
                bmpHeight, matrix, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    } else {
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me, it seems same as I posted my code